# Apply color change in Action bar navigation button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've been to the documentation, I'm still lost how to change the color on the navigation icon thing with 3 dashes near the app logo.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "thing" is the homeasupindicator icon. You can change it in your styles.xml file, by customizing your Theme, modifying the `android:homeAsUpIndicator` attribute.

In your Manifest.xml you can define your `Theme` for your whole application, or for each of your `Activities`.

So, add a style to your styles.xml, like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_indicator_drawable</item>
```

Then, on your Manifest.xml, do:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme"
```

This will override the icon on the `ActionBar`.
Don't forget to call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`; to activate the icon behaviour.

Comment: finally, i've been going around looking for the actual name of that 'thing'. thanks, i'll this code later.

Comment: btw, where can I get the drawable icons for this? I couldn't find it in the Action Bar icon pack from the developer.Android.com site.

Comment: @Martin Ongtangco You can find and download the original icons here: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html#theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C40